# ember rollback attributes when user cancel the edit action

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an app in which user can edit a product and make some changes. When user clicks the edit button, then it opens up a dialog. User can go through multiple windows and do some changes. After which, user can click save or cancel the edit action. In case of cancelling the action, I want to rollback the dirty attributes. I am using below code to do the same but somehow, some of the changes do get rollbacked while other don't. Can anyone point out if their is an issue? (below is my code for reference)

```
cancelAction() {
 if (this.get('isEditMode') && this.get('model').get('hasDirtyAttributes')) {
   this.get('model').send('becomeInvalid');
   this.get('model').rollBackAttributes();
}
```

Comment: I noticed that this is happening because control is getting passed to this function and then willDestroyElement of my component triggers which set some properties on the component. So the model is still dirty. Is there any way to avoid this or order this? Can I force willDestroyElement to trigger first.

Comment: Please, show more code especially of the component

Comment: Can you please share a working implementation show it can be debugged ?

Comment: Does that model containing relationships which you are editing, that's not getting rolled back? for ex: `product: belongsTo('some-product')` in your `models/user.js` ?

Comment: actually, the problem I noticed was the way I have the code written up. It first rollback the attributes and then as a part of cancellation process, it triggers willDestroyElement of my component which is setting the values back and hence values persists. I did some patch to identify that cancel action has happened so that willDestroyElement can be skipped.

Comment: @AbhilashLR and yes, that was another issue that model within a model will not be rolledback as ember rollback does not do a deep copy/rollback

Comment: it is true that ember rollback does not work on relationships by default, to achieve this you can iterate over the relationShips using 'model.eachRelationship' and call 'rollbackAttributes' recursively. Maybe, put this piece of code in a mixin and include in all models.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following approach:

1. Make a copy of model each time before opening a modal
2. When user makes change, work with copy
3. If user clicks "save", update original model and persist it.
4. If user clicks "cancel", no action needed.

This allows to worry less about reverting attributes and provides better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good addon for managing changes on ember-data model:
*ember-data-change-tracker*.
Currently ember-data don't track changes in object, json, custom types.
Ember-data-change-tracker support these types.